# Jquery insert table row and increment input id

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, forms

I have a dynamic html table/form that has two buttons to add a row to the table.  One button adds a row to the end of the table and increments the input id appropriately.  The other button is intended to insert a row before the current row... which it can do until I attempt to have it increment the id.  My current jquery code updates the id appropriately but strips out the  tags which results in all of the input fields being smashed into a single cell of the table.  I've included my existing code snippets below. . . what am I missing?

[link to fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6y18mho8/2/)

jquery code:

```
$(document).on('click', 'button.insertbutton', function () {
    var rowCount = $('#orderDetail tr').length;
    alert(rowCount);
    $(this).closest('tr').before($(this).closest('tr').find('input')
        .each(function() {
        $(this).attr({
          'id':  function(_, id) { 
            var regex = /[a-zA-Z]+/
            return id.match(regex) + rowCount },
          //'name':  function(_, name) { return name + rowCount },
           'value': '',
        });
      })
    ).clone(true);
    return true;
});
```

I suspect the issue is within the section where I iterate through the input items and then clone back the row.

Any guidance would be much appreciated.

EDITED TO INCLUDE FIDDLE AS RECOMMENDED... THANK YOU FOR THE RECOMMENDATION.

Comment: I'd recommend creating a fiddle, linking to it, and focusing your code snippets on the portions where you think the problem may lay.

Comment: This question should be accompanied with some HTML, no?

Comment: I had the html included and despite trying to keep it concise it was a bit long and confusing.  Per klenwell's recommendation to include a fiddle I edited the question to include a link to http://jsfiddle.net/6y18mho8/2/ which will have the html.  Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve the clone and increment ID by breaking up the operation into two steps vs trying to acomplish the task in a single line.  The jquery code for the insert and update id is as follows:

```
$(document).on('click', 'button.insertbutton', function () {
var rowCount = $('#orderDetail tr').length;
$(this).closest('tr').before($(this).closest('tr').clone());
$(this).closest('tr').find('input').each(function() {
    $(this).attr({
        'id': function(_,id) {
            var regex = /[a-zA-Z]+/
            return id.match(regex) + rowCount },
        'value': '',
    })
})

return true;
```

});

I hope this helps someone in the future